# Solace Client in C with TLS support

Tags: solace

I am trying to implement C client to connect and publish message to particular topic. I am getting below error while implementing ssl.

```
ERROR:
SDK WARNING Fri Feb 05 13:59:36.412 2021 solClientSession.c:3609              (7fb51ccfe740) Session '(c0,s1)_vpn-poc-d1': Client Certificate Authentication is not supported on unsecured sessions
ERROR:: Error in craeting session sol client.
```

Below is the implementation POC code.

```
#include "os.h"
#include "../inc/solclient/solClient.h"
#include "../inc/solclient/solClientMsg.h"


  /*****************************************************************************
   * sessionMessageReceiveCallback
   *
   * The message receive callback function is mandatory for session creation.
   *****************************************************************************/
solClient_rxMsgCallback_returnCode_t
sessionMessageReceiveCallback(solClient_opaqueSession_pt opaqueSession_p, solClient_opaqueMsg_pt msg_p, void* user_p)
{
    return SOLCLIENT_CALLBACK_OK;
}

/*****************************************************************************
 * sessionEventCallback
 *
 * The event callback function is mandatory for session creation.
 *****************************************************************************/
void
sessionEventCallback(solClient_opaqueSession_pt opaqueSession_p,
    solClient_session_eventCallbackInfo_pt eventInfo_p, void* user_p)
{
}

/*****************************************************************************
 * main
 *
 * The entry point to the application.
 *****************************************************************************/
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    /*if (argc > 1) {
        printf("Usage: TopicPublisher\n");
        return -1;
    }
*/

    /* Context */
    solClient_opaqueContext_pt context_p;
    solClient_context_createFuncInfo_t contextFuncInfo = SOLCLIENT_CONTEXT_CREATEFUNC_INITIALIZER;

    /* Session */
    solClient_opaqueSession_pt session_p;
    solClient_session_createFuncInfo_t sessionFuncInfo = SOLCLIENT_SESSION_CREATEFUNC_INITIALIZER;

    /* Session Properties */
    const char* sessionProps[40] = { 0, };
    int             propIndex = 0;

    /* Message */
    solClient_opaqueMsg_pt msg_p = NULL;
    solClient_destination_t destination;

    solClient_returnCode_t solReturnStatus = SOLCLIENT_OK;

    const char* text_p = "Hello World!!";

    /*************************************************************************
     * Initialize the API (and setup logging level)
     *************************************************************************/

     /* solClient needs to be initialized before any other API calls. */
    solReturnStatus = solClient_initialize(SOLCLIENT_LOG_DEFAULT_FILTER, NULL);
    if (solReturnStatus != SOLCLIENT_OK)
    {
        printf("ERROR:: Error in initiailizing sol client.\n");
        return -1;
    }
    printf("TopicPublisher initializing...\n");

    /*************************************************************************
     * Create a Context
     *************************************************************************/

     /*
      * Create a Context, and specify that the Context thread be created
      * automatically instead of having the application create its own
      * Context thread.
      */
    solReturnStatus = solClient_context_create(SOLCLIENT_CONTEXT_PROPS_DEFAULT_WITH_CREATE_THREAD,
        &context_p, &contextFuncInfo, sizeof(contextFuncInfo));
    if (solReturnStatus != SOLCLIENT_OK)
    {
        printf("ERROR:: Error in creating context sol client.\n");
        return -1;
    }

    /*************************************************************************
     * Create and connect a Session
     *************************************************************************/

     /*
      * Message receive callback function and the Session event function
      * are both mandatory. In this sample, default functions are used.
      */
    sessionFuncInfo.rxMsgInfo.callback_p = sessionMessageReceiveCallback;
    sessionFuncInfo.rxMsgInfo.user_p = NULL;
    sessionFuncInfo.eventInfo.callback_p = sessionEventCallback;
    sessionFuncInfo.eventInfo.user_p = NULL;

    /* Configure the Session properties. */
    propIndex = 0;

    sessionProps[propIndex++] = SOLCLIENT_SESSION_PROP_HOST;
    sessionProps[propIndex++] = argv[1];

    sessionProps[propIndex++] = SOLCLIENT_SESSION_PROP_VPN_NAME;
    sessionProps[propIndex++] = argv[2];

    sessionProps[propIndex++] = SOLCLIENT_SESSION_PROP_USERNAME;
    sessionProps[propIndex++] = argv[3];

    sessionProps[propIndex++] = SOLCLIENT_SESSION_PROP_PASSWORD;
    sessionProps[propIndex++] = argv[4];

    sessionProps[propIndex++] = SOLCLIENT_SESSION_PROP_SSL_VALIDATE_CERTIFICATE;
    sessionProps[propIndex++] = SOLCLIENT_PROP_ENABLE_VAL;

    sessionProps[propIndex++] = SOLCLIENT_SESSION_PROP_AUTHENTICATION_SCHEME;
    sessionProps[propIndex++] = SOLCLIENT_SESSION_PROP_AUTHENTICATION_SCHEME_CLIENT_CERTIFICATE;

    sessionProps[propIndex++] = SOLCLIENT_SESSION_PROP_SSL_CLIENT_CERTIFICATE_FILE;
    sessionProps[propIndex++] = argv[5];

    sessionProps[propIndex++] = SOLCLIENT_SESSION_PROP_SSL_CLIENT_PRIVATE_KEY_FILE;
    sessionProps[propIndex++] = argv[6];

    sessionProps[propIndex++] = SOLCLIENT_SESSION_PROP_SSL_CLIENT_PRIVATE_KEY_FILE_PASSWORD;
    sessionProps[propIndex++] = argv[7];

    sessionProps[propIndex++] = SOLCLIENT_SESSION_PROP_REAPPLY_SUBSCRIPTIONS;
    sessionProps[propIndex++] = SOLCLIENT_PROP_ENABLE_VAL;

    sessionProps[propIndex++] = SOLCLIENT_SESSION_PROP_SSL_VALIDATE_CERTIFICATE;
    sessionProps[propIndex++] = SOLCLIENT_PROP_DISABLE_VAL;

    sessionProps[propIndex++] = SOLCLIENT_SESSION_PROP_SSL_EXCLUDED_PROTOCOLS;
    sessionProps[propIndex++] = "TLSv1.1";

    sessionProps[propIndex++] = SOLCLIENT_SESSION_PROP_RECONNECT_RETRIES;
    sessionProps[propIndex++] = "3";

    sessionProps[propIndex++] = SOLCLIENT_SESSION_PROP_CONNECT_RETRIES_PER_HOST;
    sessionProps[propIndex++] = "3";

    sessionProps[propIndex++] = SOLCLIENT_SESSION_PROP_SSL_VALIDATE_CERTIFICATE_DATE;
    sessionProps[propIndex++] = SOLCLIENT_PROP_DISABLE_VAL;

    sessionProps[propIndex++] = SOLCLIENT_SESSION_PROP_SSL_TRUST_STORE_DIR;
    sessionProps[propIndex++] = argv[8];

    sessionProps[propIndex++] = SOLCLIENT_SESSION_PROP_SSL_CIPHER_SUITES;
    sessionProps[propIndex++] = SOLCLIENT_SESSION_PROP_SSL_CIPHER_TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA;

    sessionProps[propIndex++] = SOLCLIENT_SESSION_PROP_SSL_TRUSTED_COMMON_NAME_LIST;
    sessionProps[propIndex++] = "TEST";

    sessionProps[propIndex++] = SOLCLIENT_SESSION_PROP_SSL_CONNECTION_DOWNGRADE_TO;
    sessionProps[propIndex++] = "PLAIN_TEXT";

    sessionProps[propIndex] = NULL;
    printf("Total Properties set = %d\n",propIndex);

    /* Create the Session. */
    solReturnStatus = solClient_session_create((char**)sessionProps,
        context_p,
        &session_p, &sessionFuncInfo, sizeof(sessionFuncInfo));
    if (solReturnStatus != SOLCLIENT_OK)
    {
        printf("ERROR:: Error in craeting session sol client.\n");
        return -1;
    }

    /* Connect the Session. */
    solReturnStatus = solClient_session_connect(session_p);

    if (solReturnStatus != SOLCLIENT_OK)
    {
        printf("ERROR:: Error in connecting to session sol client.\n");
        return -1;
    }
    printf("Connected.\n");

    /*************************************************************************
     * Publish
     *************************************************************************/

     /* Allocate memory for the message that is to be sent. */
    solClient_msg_alloc(&msg_p);

    /* Set the message delivery mode. */
    solClient_msg_setDeliveryMode(msg_p, SOLCLIENT_DELIVERY_MODE_DIRECT);

    /* Set the destination. */
    destination.destType = SOLCLIENT_TOPIC_DESTINATION;
    destination.dest = argv[9];
    solClient_msg_setDestination(msg_p, &destination, sizeof(destination));

    /* Add some content to the message. */
    solClient_msg_setBinaryAttachment(msg_p, text_p, (solClient_uint32_t)strlen((char*)text_p));

    /* Send the message. */
    printf("About to send message '%s' to topic '%s'...\n", (char*)text_p, argv[9]);
    solReturnStatus = solClient_session_sendMsg(session_p, msg_p);
    if (solReturnStatus != SOLCLIENT_OK)
    {
        printf("ERROR:: Error in sending data to topic.\n");
    }

    /* Free the message. */
    printf("Message sent. Exiting.\n");
    solReturnStatus = solClient_msg_free(&msg_p);
    if (solReturnStatus != SOLCLIENT_OK)
    {
        printf("ERROR:: Error in msg free sol client.\n");
    }

    /*************************************************************************
     * Cleanup
     *************************************************************************/

     /* Cleanup solClient. */
    solReturnStatus = solClient_cleanup();

    if (solReturnStatus != SOLCLIENT_OK)
    {
        printf("ERROR:: Error in cleanup sol client.\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I might be using invalid certificates, is there any way to get the correct certificates from pubsub+ solace server?

Answer (score 0):

The error "Client Certificate Authentication is not supported on unsecured sessions" means that you are using a plain-text connection, but trying to authentication with client certificates, which is not supported.

This is likely because you are attempting to connect to the default port 55555, which is a plaintext port. To fix this, use the SSL port instead. By default, the SMF SSL port is 55443. You must also ensure this port is enabled and the server certificate is configured on the broker side. All the other configuration in your code snippet looks correct.